# MASM addressing mode syntax

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, nasm, masm

Here are 2 lines that have resulted from a disassembler that generates Microsoft ASM
assembly:

```
mov    dl, loc_0040540c[edx]
jmp    dword ptr [loc_00405450][edx*4]
```

Can someone explain what do they mean?
I work mostly with NASM so a NASM equivalent would be good as well.

Comment: Have you sure that NASM has the concept for `2D-array`? usually,it's HLL-thing. Usually,the memory is continuos like a byte-sequence of your characters.

Comment: This is just weird microsoft syntax, you can't use 2D arrays like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NASM-speak:

```
mov    dl, [loc_0040540c + edx]
jmp    [loc_00405450 + edx*4]
```

And those `loc_0040540c` are probably the respective addresses/constants (e.g. `0040540cH`).

Comment: At a first glance, I couldn't honestly see the difference between the two syntaxes...

Comment: @JosephH And in this case there isn't much. Now, if you do `BLAH DD 123`, then `MOV EAX, BLAH` in NASM is going to do something very different compared to MASM and TASM.

Comment: Thanks!
One more question: MASM uses st(0) when working with floats, what is the NASM equivalent?